# Cartesian product $\mathbb R^m \times E$ is measurable for $E \subset \mathbb R^n$ measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to show that given $E \subset \mathbb R^n$ measurable, then $\mathbb R^m \times E \subset \mathbb R^{m+n}$ is measurable but I don't have a clue how to show this. I could think of the following:

If $E$ is a measurable set, then $E=H \setminus N$, with $H$ a $G_{\delta}$ set and $N$ a null set, so $H= \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} G_n$, with $G_n$ is open.

So $$\mathbb R^m \times E= \mathbb R^m \times (H \setminus N)$$$$=(\mathbb R^m \times \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} G_n) \setminus (\mathbb R^m \times N)$$$$=\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} (\mathbb R^m \times G_n) \setminus (\mathbb R^m \times N)$$

So it is sufficient to prove the proposition for open and null sets. I would appreciate help to show the proposition for these two types of sets. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For open sets, the product is also open.

For the case of null sets, use the definition of the Lebesgue outer measure to show that of $E $ is null, then so is $[-N,N]^m\times E $ for arbitrary $N $. Then take countable unions.